# Kodein and activity context discuss

Tags: android, android-context, kodein

I have researched this example [repo](https://github.com/suchoX/Kodein-MVVM/tree/master/app) to understand how to implement Kodein in the Android app.
But I was confused about the context questions in the activity case in the example.

Here the code:

```
  abstract class BaseActivity<B : ViewDataBinding, VM : ViewModel>: AppCompatActivity(), KodeinAware {

  protected lateinit var binding: B
  lateinit var viewModel: VM
  private val _parentKodein by closestKodein()

  override val kodein: Kodein by retainedKodein {
    extend(_parentKodein, copy = Copy.All)
    bind<Activity>() with singleton { this@BaseActivity }
    bind<Context>("ActivityContext") with singleton { this@BaseActivity }
    import(activityModule)
  }
}
```

Here we see that we add the context of activity to the singleton.

But also I see that we get `Kodein` by `retainedKodein` function. 
So this Kodein module has immune to activity destroying on rotation.
But I do not understand about activity's context, because singleton holds the context.

So I ask. Does Kodein reattach the context of activity? Could you describe to me the reattach mechanism? Because this is not clear for me now. Thank you guys!:))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is no way! Kodein can not reatach activity context to his instance.
I have used leackcanary util and found activity leacks in sample [repo](https://github.com/suchoX/Kodein-MVVM/tree/master/app), also created
[isuue](https://github.com/suchoX/Kodein-MVVM/issues/3)

There is leackcanary result: [image]